# How to change G Suite SDK visibility from Domain to Public?

Tags: google-workspace

Does anyone know how to do it ?

I checked their Documentation and it is said,

Warning: Once you select and save a visibility setting, you cannot change it later.

If it is not allowed,  is there any work-around?  I've tried disable G Suite SDK , not work.